# How to use restful_authentication for nested resources in Rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

I have a nested resource hotel_user and i wish to have hotel_users_controller under hotel namespace.

I want to use restful authentication here and I want hotel_users_controller, sessions_controller in hotel directory like hotel/hotel_users_controller and hotel/sessions_controller. I tried with the following command in terminal and it failed.

```
script/generate authenticated hotel_user hotel/session
```

and it failed with the error

```
 The name 'AuthenticatedSystem' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails.
  Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

The authenticated_system.rb file exists for some other resource under lib directory and not for hotel_user. the generator is seeing it and fails the generation of files. what can I do? please help

Comment: FWIW, my Ruby & Rails friends tell me that "no one uses restful-authentication anymore," but instead use newer plugins like Authlogic, cancan, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change your file_name and module name.

Regenerate your restful_authentication and change it with other name. Or you previous file.

Comment: thanks, I will use authlogic as recommended by the commentor on my question above